# Error when calling biosphere flows an activity in ecoinvent v.3.5

Tags: brightway

I happen to face an error when I try to call the biosphere flows of activity. And When I call the technosphere for different activities, it works fine.

However, for the biosphere:

```
[in] clinker_bio_exchange = [exc for exc in clinker.biosphere()]
clinker_bio_exchange
```

Error:

```html
        ActivityDatasetDoesNotExist: <Model: ActivityDataset> instance matching query does not exist:
        SQL: SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."data", "t1"."code", "t1"."database", "t1"."location", "t1"."name", "t1"."product", "t1"."type" FROM "activitydataset" AS "t1" WHERE (("t1"."database" = ?) AND ("t1"."code" = ?)) ORDER BY Random() LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
        Params: ['biosphere3', 'fc1c42ce-a759-49fa-b987-f1ec5e503db1', 1, 0]
```

Should I update any part or am I missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with your `biosphere3` database - your `clinker` object has an exchange with the biosphere flow (activity) `('biosphere3', 'fc1c42ce-a759-49fa-b987-f1ec5e503db1')` (which is `Water, cooling, unspecified natural origin` on my machine). However, you are either missing the `biosphere3` database entirely, or have deleted or otherwise modified this specific flow.

The easiest way to fix this is to reinstall it:

```
import bw2io
bw2io.create_default_biosphere3()
```